# How can I convert my normal angular project into a vs code extension?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am having one angular 12 project available. Now I want to convert this project or say I want to make VS Code extension from this angular project.
Is there any way to build angular project and load it as a VS Code extension?

Comment: you can make any HTML-JavaScript into a WebviewView or WebView

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

As stated above, [Webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#webviews-api-basics) API offers that. There are also a lot of official [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples), including one for [Angular](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/frameworks/hello-world-angular).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through the [Webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#webviews-api-basics) of VSCode. This will allow you to embed your Angular project as a VSCode extension.